# Image zoom with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, zooming

I've been searching for what plug in is used in these 2 sites for the full screen image viewing:

- [Product zoom example 1](http://www.zara.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product/fr/en/zara-S2012/190033/718530/DRAPE+NECK+COAT#content)
- [Product zoom example 2](http://fr.topshop.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?beginIndex=0&viewAllFlag=&catalogId=34056&storeId=13057&productId=4866706&langId=-2&sort_field=Relevance&categoryId=345717&parent_categoryId=345707&pageSize=20)

I'm searching for a jQuery module (or tutorial) that would do something similar. Note that I'm talking about the FULL SCREEN PICTURE when you CLICK on the product image, not the "CloudZoom" feature when your mouse is over the image.
I'm currently using the widely used Lightbox module with CloudZoom, but the image loaded by Lightbox is way to big (because the href points to a BIG image, for the CloudZoom zoom).

What I need here is to have an image that uses the full browser size (not bigger than the current browser, as the lightbox creates an opaque dark background that only takes the browser's height. If my image is bigger, the user can scroll down but the lightbox dark background doesn't fill up the page).

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the link on which you can get the image [zoom plugin](http://jacklmoore.com/zoom/) which might help you.

[Zoom Effect plugin](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php#demo5) as per your example 2

**UPDATE:**

Here is the jQuery [fullscreen image gallery](http://manos.malihu.gr/sideways-jquery-fullscreen-image-gallery)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Happy Singh. I realized I wasn't clear in my question, I know the module that is used for the image zooming on mouse over, I actually need a module that handles the _full screen image viewing_ when you click on the product picture (sort of lightbox). Thanks again !

Comment: I see, thanks for the fullscreen image gallery ! Looks like this will do ! It looks like my example 1 link, except they have a feature that allows to scroll up and down the image using the mouse position over the image. Do you think this is custom ? Thanks

Comment: Every thing is custom we can customize the things acc to our requirement.try it to change the code and css and you will get the exact what you want but it requires sound knowledge of language. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3):

You should also give [Supersized](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) a look. I've used it for a couple of projects and have never had an issue with it. It's very customizable.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out "CloudZoom" which usess image tiles. This way your original image can be as large as you want - 10mp, 20mp or even 100mp if you like: http://www.ajax-zoom.com/examples/example20.php Fullscreen is also supported if you click on that image.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<div id="Gpic1"><img id='table' src='http://i.imgur.com/7ESpNI8.jpg'></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#Gpic1').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('img').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('img').fadeTo(500, 1);
    });

$('#table').click(function() {
        $('#Gpic1').find('img').fadeTo(0, 1);
        if($('#table').hasClass('enlarged')){
            $('#table').removeClass('enlarged');
            $("#table").stop().animate({width: 280, height: 187}, 200 );
        }else{
            $('#table').addClass('enlarged')
            $("#table").stop().animate({width: 800, height: 533}, 200 );
        }

    });
```

**css**

```
#Gpic1{
    width: 280px;
    height: 187px;
    display: block;
    background: black;
}

#table{
    width: 280px;
    height: 187px;
}
```

[Jsfiddl demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4LUYM/)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried: [Touch Gallery?](http://neteye.github.com/touch-gallery.html)